# Loading Form Element based on Select Values in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile in my App. I want to show some form fields based on the select values. Here's my jQuery code

```
$( document ).bind( "pageinit", function( event, data ) {
$("#marrystatus").css("display","none");


    $("#marital_status").click(function(){
    if ($('#marital_status option:selected').val() == "Married" ) {
        $("#marrystatus").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

    } else {
        $("#marrystatus").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect

    }
 });
```

});

Here's my HTML code

```
    <li id="marrystatus" data-role="fieldcontain" > 

    <label for="marriedto"></label> 
    <input type="text" name="marriedto" id="marriedto" 
placeholder="Married To" /> 

    <label for="marryanidate"></label> 
    <input type="text" name="marryanidate" id="marryanidate" 
placeholder="Marrige Anniversary Date (DD/MM/YYYY)" /> 
  </li>
```

The code works fine in normal browsers like Google Chrome on Windows 7, but on my Android, it doesn't work. Is their any fix ?

Comment: Try another android browser e.g Dolphin

Comment: Why are you specifying 'option: selected'?

Comment: I fixed it by changing the click() to change() function